# Issues with OdbcDataReader

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here's my code for reading my db data:

```
OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();           
while (rdr.Read())
{
    PetraStruct.TFmTop TempTop = new PetraStruct.TFmTop();
    TempTop.Name = (string)rdr["TOPNAME"];
    TempTop.MD = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["MD"]);
}
rdr.Close();
```

After running `cmd.ExecuteReader()`, I can see my reader has results:

[image: Results can be seen]

For some reason, when `while(rdr.Read())` is excuted, rdr.Read() returns false, and my results are blown away:

[image: Results gone]

My whole while block is skipped, and I end up at `rdr.Close()`.

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be going on, and how my results get blown away when I try to read them?

Comment: Have you tried running it without looking at the content with debugger? As debugger could possibly iterate your query and there will be nothing to iterate more for code.

Comment: @Archeg The body of the while loop creates an object, writes values to a couple of its properties, and does nothing else with the object.  It never reads any value.  How could running it outside the debugger help?

Comment: @phoog - no - Archeg's point is that the process of looking at the results in the debugger will enumerate the results on the reader and "consume" all your results. I think Archeg is just trying to eliminate that as a cause of your problem. (the first time you click on the bit that says "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" it will consume the results from the reader)

Comment: @RobLevine I understand Archeg's point.  (The problem is not "mine", by the way.)  My point is that running the code outside the debugger *will have no effect* because the code in the while loop produces no output that could be observed outside the scope of the while loop (barring some side effect such as logging code in the property setters or constructor).

Comment: @phoog - yeah - point taken. And yes - I confused you for the OP :)

Comment: @RobLevine it's easy to do -- I make the same mistake all the time.

Comment: @RobLevine, @Archeg - You're both correct. By enumerating the results in the debugger, I was "consuming" them, and that's why my `rdr.Read()` was evaluating as false. There was nothing left for the code to iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Debug->Exceptions menu? Not all exceptions are enabled by default, that's why you are confused. Enable all of them and then you'll see what is going on.

Comment: Ok, so I'm completely baffled. I went into Debug->Exceptions and enabled everything then reran my code (with absolutely no changes whatsoever), and the thing now runs perfectly. I'm glad to be passed this issue that's cost me a day already, but I'm just baffled as to what just happened to make it work.

Comment: That's confusing to me as well. Be enabling all exceptions I meant that you will find where the error is... :\